# How to join Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 to Windows Server 2019 Active Directory?

Tags: server, 18.04, windows, active-directory

I tried different guides online but none of them worked. Is there any GUI way to join AD with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04?
The error message I always get: couldn't join realm insufficient permissions to join the domain
Maybe I should set something on the windows server?
I can ping the Windows AD domain controller from the Ubuntu client, Windows Server DHCP gives IP to Ubuntu client after install.
I just want to see the Ubuntu machine name in the AD on Windows server.